# reordering selected column of data.table in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data table dt[] which contains 500 columns, I need to pick 6 columns say (a,c,k,m,n,o) from the data table and put them in the starting of the data table.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a vector of columns of interest ('nm1'), then concatenate that with the column names that are found in 'nm1' (using `setdiff`.  In `data.table`, for subsetting columns, we use `with = FALSE`.

```
nm1 <- c('a', 'c' 'k', 'm', 'n', 'o')
dt[, c(nm1, setdiff(names(dt1), nm1)), with=FALSE]
```

Other option include `setcolorder`, but the above method is more convenient as it will not replace the order in the original dataset.

NOTE: No external packages used.

Answer (score 0):

Whether dealing with `data.frame`s or `data.table`s, I would suggest loading "data.table" and using `setcolorder`.

Paired up with [`moveMe`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/moveMe.R) from [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun), you have a very flexible means of reordering columns.

Loading package and creating sample data:

```
library(SOfun)
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(as.list(setNames(1:26, letters)))
DF <- setDF(copy(DT))
DT
#    a b c d e f g h i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
# 1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

DF
#   a b c d e f g h i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
# 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Moving columns:

```
setcolorder(DT, moveMe(names(DT), "a,c,k,m,n,o first"))
DT
#    a c  k  m  n  o b d e f g h i  j  l  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
# 1: 1 3 11 13 14 15 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

setcolorder(DF, moveMe(names(DF), "a,c,k,m,n,o first"))
DF
#   a c  k  m  n  o b d e f g h i  j  l  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
# 1 1 3 11 13 14 15 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Beyond "first", you also have "last", "before", and "after".

```
setcolorder(DF, moveMe(names(DF), "a,c,k,m,n,o first; l,e,q,r,w last"))
DF
#   a c  k  m  n  o b d f g h i  j  p  s  t  u  v  x  y  z  l e  q  r  w
# 1 1 3 11 13 14 15 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 16 19 20 21 22 24 25 26 12 5 17 18 23
```